# XSLT variable not working

Tags: xml, vb.net, xslt

I have below xsl code but it is not working, could anybody please guide me.

```
<xsl:variable name="indent">
    <xsl:if test="@type='Text'">
        <xsl:if test="@required='yes'">
            <xsl:variable name="indent" select="'return ValidateText(this)'" />
        </xsl:if>
        <asp:TextBox id="{@id}" onkeypress="{$indent}" runat="server" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>
```

I need to assign return `ValidateText(this)` onkeypress even if inside xml the required is yes.

Comment: "is not working", without a statement of *how* it's not working (e.g. XSLT processor gives an error), seems to indicate that you want us to do a lot of guesswork instead of you doing the work of stating the question clearly.

Comment: @LarsH and @Khan: The not working part is evidently the use of innermost `indent` variable outside of its scope. In XSLT 2.0 this raise an error because circular definition: the use of outermost `indent` value into its own content template. In XSLT silently, evaluate variable reference to nothing.

Comment: @Alejandro: yes, I saw that but I see this "not working" thing so often, presented as if it were a complete statement of the problem, I thought it was worth pointing out to Khan. Why should you and I be doing the work of investigating and typing that in, when he has the error in front of him? or at least he can say that the indent variable ends up with an empty value. He has some information by which he knows that it's not working; as someone who's asking for help, decency says he should share that information. @Khan, see http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: It's like Nebuchadnezzar's dream (http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=daniel%202:1-6&version=ESV)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to get exactly what you are after but I'd make the following guess

```
<xsl:if test="@type='Text'>
    <asp:TextBox id="{@id}" runat="server" >
        <xsl:if test="@required='yes'">
            <xsl:attribute name="onkeypress">
                <xsl:text>return ValidateText(this)</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
    </asp:TextBox>
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

**It is not at all clear what exactly is wanted, but my guess is you want something like this**:

```
<xsl:variable name="indent">
 <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="@type='Text' and @required='yes'">
    <xsl:text>return ValidateText(this)</xsl:text>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>someDefault</xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<asp:TextBox id="{@id}" onkeypress="{$indent}" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Other one guessing, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:asp="remove">
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*/*">
        <xsl:variable name="indent">
            <xsl:if test="@type='Text'">
                <asp:TextBox id="{@id}" 
                             onkeypress="{substring('return ValidateText(this)',
                                                    1 div (@required='yes'))}"
                             runat="server" />
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$indent"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<root>
    <form id="form1" type='Text' required="yes"/>
    <form id="form2" type='Text' required="no"/>
    <form id="form3" type='Input' required="yes"/>
</root>
```

Output:

```
<root>
    <asp:TextBox id="form1" onkeypress="return ValidateText(this)" runat="server" xmlns:asp="remove" />
    <asp:TextBox id="form2" onkeypress="" runat="server" xmlns:asp="remove" />
</root>
```